# Add gender column searching rows that contains info from 2 tables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a df that contains some emails:

```
Email
jonathat0420@email.com
12alexander@email.com
14abcdjoanna@email.com
maria44th@email.com
mikeasddf@email.com
```

I need to add a second column with the gender.
I will have 2 lists:

```
male_names = ['john', 'alex']
female_names = ['maria', joanna']
```

My output should look like that:

```
Email                      Gender
jonathat0420@email.com     1
12alexander@email.com      1
14abcdjoanna@email.com     2
maria44th@email.com        2
mikeasddf@email.com
```

I would need to search the emails that contains the names from the lists and if they are in the emails to add them a number, like "1" for males, 2 for "females" and leave empty for the emails without matching in the lists.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a map, like this:

```
def isinlist(email, names):
    for name in names:
        if name in email:
            return True
    return False

df.loc[:, 'Gender'] = df.Email.map(lambda x : 1 if isinlist(x, male_names) else (2 if isinlist(x, female_names) else None))
```

However, there are going to be a lot of ambiguous cases that risk being classified erroneously - e.g., "alexandra@email.com" would be classified as male, since alex is the list of male names.
Maybe you could implement a slighly more complex "best match" logic like this?

```
def maxmatchlen(email, names): # = length of longest name from list that is contained in the email
    return max([len(name) for name in names if name in email] + [0]) # append a 0 to avoid empty lists
    
def f(email, male_names = male_names, female_names = female_names):
    male_maxmatchlen   = maxmatchlen(email, male_names)
    female_maxmatchlen = maxmatchlen(email, female_names)
    if male_maxmatchlen > female_maxmatchlen:
        return 1
    elif female_maxmatchlen > male_maxmatchlen:
        return 2
    else: # ambiguous case
        return None

df.loc[:, 'Gender'] = df.Email.map(f)
```

Comment: I think it'd be more efficient to store the names and resultant flags in a single list-of-tuples, sorted by descending name length...

Comment: @Elena Fortina Thank you for the improved answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you first must determine if the email contains a name.  You can loop through both male and female.  That will determine if the name is "in" the email.   Then you could make a list or a dictionary of these.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

def get_emails(filepath):
    """Open the data file and read the lines - return a list"""
    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        email_list = f.readlines()  
    for email in email_list:
        print(f'Email = {email}')
    print(f'The total number of emails = {len(email_list)}')
    return email_list

def find_names(email_list):

    """loop through the email list and see if each one contains a male or female name - return dictionary of tuples"""
    male_names = ['john', 'alex', 'mike', 'jonathat']
    female_names = ['maria', 'joanna']
    name_dict = {}
    for email in email_list:
        for name_f in female_names:
            if name_f in email:
                data= (name_f , 1)
                name_dict[email] = data
                print(f"{email} is for {name_f} and is female {data[1]}")
                continue
        for name_m in male_names:
            if name_m in email:
                data= (name_m , 2)
                name_dict[email] = data
                print(f"{email} is for {name_m} and is male {data[1]}")
                continue
    return name_dict
        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    your_Datafile = r"D:\Share\email.txt"
    email_list = get_emails(your_Datafile)
    my_dictionary = find_names(email_list)
    print(my_dictionary)
    for email, data in my_dictionary.items():
        print(data[0], data[1], email)
```